# Microsoft Visual Studio Isolated Shell 2015

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-extensions

for some time I work with Visual Studio isolated shell.
So I have some question about it:

1. Can I edit the ***Blank Solution***? When how?
2. Or can I add my own ***Template*** in the isolated Shell?

I already searched for a answer on **msdn-sites** and tried some of them out, with **no success**.

**What I want:** When I create a new project file in the isolated shell than I can only use the Blank Soltution (BS). I want to put my own template (.zip file or project template) next to the BS or replace it. My own template have some items that should always come out when someone creates a new project file.

Comment: 1.Can I edit the Blank Solution? How?  please describe it in detailed. 2..Or can I add my own exported Template in the isolated Shell? Do want to Extend the Isolated Shell with 
Visual Studio Package Project Template, like this:https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee524005.aspx

Comment: please answere the question